# Make e.target.value a variable - Javascript

Tags: javascript

First timer here. Into the question.
Background:
I have a personality test that is based off of the PHQ9 questionnaire. Currently I am pulling the questions from my PSQL DB and have them formatted appropriately with Jinja and select/option fields. I can see in the developer console that I am receiving the **e.target.value** from the options that are selected.

```html
      <ol id="questionList">
            {% for questions in questions %}
            <li class="questions">{{questions.question}}</li>
            <select id="options" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3">
              <option selected>Please select an option</option>
              <option class="option1" value="0">Not at all</option>
              <option class="option2" value="1">Several days</option>
              <option class="option3" value="2">More than half the days</option>
              <option class="option4" value="3">Nearly every day</option>
            </select>
            {% endfor %}
          </ol>
```

I used javascript to create console.log of the values so I can make sure that the values match the level assigned.
Ex: Not at all = 0, Several days = 1, etc...

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("#questionList select")].map((o) =>
  o.addEventListener("change", (e) => e.target.value)
);
```

However I am having a difficult time understanding how to destruct the console.log and turn the e.target.value to a variable that can be pushed to a score array and produce a sum at the end.

Comment: I don't see any `console.log` in the code you provided. It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: `e.target.value` will be a string so if you want to do some sums with numbers in an array it would be best to coerce it to a number. And you can just push `e.target.value` right into the array: `arr.push(Number(e.target.value))`. A destructuring approach would be `const { value } = e.target; arr.push(Number(value));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need I think. Also at the end you can have a look at [how to sum the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
      let arrayOfScores = [];
      [...document.querySelectorAll("#questionList select")].map((o) =>
        o.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
          arrayOfScores.push(Number(e.target.value))
          console.log(arrayOfScores); // This is just to check the array that it works
        })
      );
```

OR you can add a score and add the answer value to it.

```
 let score = 0;
      [...document.querySelectorAll("#questionList select")].map((o) =>
        o.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
          score += Number(e.target.value)
        })
      );
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you so much! Also, thank you for providing the link to sum array.